# What time does it take by python to calculate float("inf")?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve leetcode question [#1448](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-good-nodes-in-binary-tree/) using recursive dfs (solution provided from leetcode) whose run time is O(n). Given the test cases it took **244ms** to run.

```
class Solution:
    def goodNodes(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
    
        def dfs(node, max_so_far):
            nonlocal num_good_nodes
            if max_so_far <= node.val:
                num_good_nodes += 1
            if node.right:
                dfs(node.right, max(node.val, max_so_far))
            if node.left:
                dfs(node.left, max(node.val, max_so_far))
        
        num_good_nodes = 0
        dfs(root, float("-inf"))
        return num_good_nodes
```

But when I change `float("-inf")` to `root.val`(-10^4<=root.val<= 10^4) time taken by same test cases reduces to **240ms**. I was wondering what's going behind the scene when using `float("inf")` or what factors in time taken for its calculation.

Comment: I try to run `float("inf")`, it only take 0.001 sec.

Comment: Leetcode will show different time for the same submission. I think ```float('-inf')``` doesn't have anything to do with it. You could try re-submitting the same solution and you'll see the time difference.

Comment: When you use `float` you have a function call. With `root.val` you have not.

Comment: Keep in mind that computers will different specs will run the same functions at different speeds, and that there are many sources of timing variation (different arguments, CPython garbage collection, multitasking operating system switching to another process, ...)

Comment: @Ram yes I tried submitting the same solution multiple time it was different each time. As batwannabe suggested it may be due to multiple OS processes and other similar factor.  Also what matthias reasoned makes sense too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the construction of `float("inf")` or `float("-inf")` is really relevant here.  If you're really curious you can see how it's implemented you can find that here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b56b3b97d91e2b412ce1b2bcaddcd43ef3d223b/Objects/floatobject.c#L181

It is a *little* non-trivial just because it has to do some checks like "is this a string?" and "is this an ASCII string?" as well as some bits for handling locale oddities, before passing it off to the system's string-to-double function (e.g. something like [`strtod`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/strtod.html).

But again, this should be very fast.  Though surprisingly a *bit* more involved than a normal attribute lookup on a Python object, albeit marginally (and this could depend on a lot of things as well):

```
In [1]: %timeit float("inf")
97.4 ns ± 5.64 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [2]: class A: pass

In [3]: a = A()

In [4]: a.x = 1

In [5]: %timeit a.x
34.4 ns ± 2.23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

This is partly because `float(<whatever>)` still has to go through all the object construction code (calling `__new__`, etc.) which can be a bit involved in Python.

In your code that line is only being called once, so it shouldn't be having a big impact.  A 4ms difference is pretty marginal anyways and could be caused by anything.  You didn't even tell us what the value of `root.val` is...